# File not being sent in Postman

Tags: file-upload, postman, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a file in Postman native to test our API, but I can't get it sent. I've set Request method POST, chosen BODY and added a file (using the file selector) and given the file the key I want it to have. I've also added another key-value (string), which gets sent. This is the request:

```
POST /api/user/1901594/17406/foto HTTP/1.1
Host: hidden.domain.com
tp-api-token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6ImF4a3Jpc3RpYW5zZW4iLCJ0dGwiOjE1NTYwNDQ0NDh9.7MAp43_4jnPM_QQluc2Ozx-QBowjCIqQzJ8sn9Y7HG0
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 8c14c293-f769-4391-90a3-c070cba1393a
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---- 
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foto"; filename="C:\Users\ander\Downloads\bilder tilhenger\DSC_0178.JPG



Content-Disposition: form-data; name="unikID"

asdf2398
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

As you can see the filename is added to the request, but not the actual file itself (it should be, shouldn't it?)

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the Postman request. It was the PHP extension php-fileinfo who wasn't installed on our new server.